# CreateOrAppendToCustomConf() [F] failed to create '/etc/gitea/app.ini': mkdir /etc/gitea: permission denied

Tags: gitea

I made a gitea migration from localhost to docker container.
I dump data and clone repository to docker container, after clone git from gitea container server and do push code I get this error.

```
remote: 2021/11/06 15:37:09 ...s/setting/setting.go:1164:CreateOrAppendToCustomConf() [F] failed to create '/etc/gitea/app.ini': mkdir /etc/gitea: permission denied
To http://192.168.2.10:3333/ICS2020SW/vdicom.git
 ! [remote rejected] origin/feature/unit-test-vdicom -> origin/feature/unit-test-vdicom (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://192.168.2.10:3333/ICS2020SW/vdicom.git'
```

What I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

I faced kind of the same issue. On checking the docs (https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/backup-and-restore/ ), I found the description in the last section:

> Repository git-hooks should be regenerated if installation method is changed (eg. binary -> Docker), or if Gitea is installed to a different directory than the previous installation.
>
> With Gitea running, and from the directory Gitea’s binary is located, execute: `./gitea admin regenerate hooks`
>
>
> This ensures that application and configuration file paths in repository git-hooks are consistent and applicable to the current installation. If these paths are not updated, repository push actions will fail.

This pretty much did it.